# Fetching a image in server context path from javascript code

Tags: javascript, image, websphere

I have a spring based web application **MyWebapp** built using maven and deployed on Websphere 6.1

The folder structure is:

**MyApp --> src ---> main --->**

The **main** folder is further having **resources** and **webapp** folders.

webapp folders is having other folders like **images, theme, jscript, JSP, META-INF, WEB-INF**

images folder is having **icons** folder with say **example.png**

So fetching **example.png** on localhost as:

```
http://localhost:9080/MyWebapp/images/icons/example.png
```

succeeds.

In **jscript** folder I have a **sample.js** javascript file where some functions are defined.

I am importing this javascript file in JSP pages as:

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jscript/sample.js" type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"></script>
```

This javascript file is having a function which tries to fetch image as below:

```
iconFile = '../images/icons/search_result.png';  
anchor.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + iconFile + ')'; 
anchor.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';        
anchor.style.backgroundPosition = '1px 2px';        
anchor.className = 'toplevel-tab';
```

The complete function basically tries to place a icon before some text in JSP.

The code gets parsed. However, the image does not get displayed.

Running the code independently on a simple html with the png images in the same folder as html and javascript files succeeds. Here i will just have iconFile = "search_result.png"

So, it is not code issue.

Issue is that the image is not getting located or the server is unable to find the image in above javascript code.

What am I doing wrong ? 
How can I solve it ?

The answer for https://stackoverflow.com/a/8298652/887235 which I accepted earlier does not work. 
**So please do not downvote this question as a duplicate one.**

Also I am working on restricted environment where access to programs like Tail will not work.

Changing

```
iconFile = '../images/icons/search_result.png';
```

to

```
iconFile = '/images/icons/search_result.png';
```

also does not work!!

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to understand how relative paths work. Even if the path is in a JavaScript file, the path is not relative to the location of this JS file, but it's relative to the URL of the HTML page being displayed in the browser.

So, if the URL of the page executing this javascript code is

```
http://foo.bar.com/myWebApp/zim/boom/tchak.html
```

and the URL of the image is

```
../images/icons/search_result.png
```

The absolute URL of the image will be

```
http://foo.bar.com/myWebApp/zim/boom/../images/icons/search_result.png
```

which is the same as

```
http://foo.bar.com/myWebApp/zim/images/icons/search_result.png
```

An absolute path like `/images/icons/search_result.png` is also resolved from the root of the web server, and not the root of the webapp (the browser doesn't know what a Java webapp is and doesn't care). So it's resolved as

```
http://foo.bar.com/images/icons/search_result.png
```

You would need to prepend the context path to the path to make it really absolute:

```
<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/icons/search_result.png
```

or, without scriptlets:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icons/search_result.png
```

Comment: directly prepending <%=request.getContextPath()%> in the code in javascript file will not work right ?

Comment: No it won't. You should store the result of ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in a globa JavaScript variable in the JSP. See my comment on graphicdivine's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give your javascript an awareness of the path to the root of your application, as this will change on context.  Start by declaring a global variable, such as:

```
<script>
    var siteroot = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
</script>
```

Then, you are ready to use it later, such as:

```
iconFile = siteroot + '/images/icons/search_result.png';
```

Comment: The declaration of global variable -- will this go into the JSP file or the javascript file ?? Or it does not matter ?

Comment: SInce it's surrounded with <script> tags, it's obviously in the JSP file. JS files are not interpreted by the JSP engine, and <%=request.getContextPath()%> would thus have no sense in a JS file

Comment: The JSP.  It needs to run server-side.

Comment: Ok. I added <script> var siteroot = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>"; </script> in the JSP. But then using siteroot in js file in the function shows 'siteroot' can not be resolved. Even though am getting this error in javascript file, the images did got picked where they are needed. So is it ok to ignore this error ???

Comment: Did you declare 'siteroot' *before* you tried to use it? What do you get if you 'alert' siteroot immediately after you declare it?

Comment: @graphicdivine: The alert correctly shows the root. Also the alert I placed in the javascript file comes after siteroot alert. So obviously it is getting run after siteroot. And the error I am speaking about is eclipse error. siteroot underlined as red and on mouse over showing 'siteroot' can not be resolved.

Comment: I know nothing about eclipse, I'm afraid.  If it works and you can ignore the error, then I'm sure it's safe to do so.  Perhaps there is some way to define (or re-define) the var in a way that will satisfy eclipse?

Comment: @Nikunj: Eclipse displays an error because it's unaware that your JS file wil be used in a page where the variable is declared before, outside of the JS file. Just ignore the error.