# Not able to load image using context root in java dynamic project

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

I am developing project in java and there is a requirement to load logo or image but could not able to load from jsp. I have placed images in all possible places like under webcontent , WEB-INF but no luck to load but from a https url i am able to load images . I need a help to load images through context root . Please help on this .

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkUGZ.png)

[Web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvM4T.png)

[JSP/HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke3jX.png)

Comment: can you please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487724/fetching-a-image-in-server-context-path-from-javascript-code

Comment: Thanks Ganesh . I have tried the options which you suggested but somehow its not working for me . If you check above of my code it works if i load image from https but not from context root . Not sure if any problem by servlet which dosnt allow .